# Creating a bubble chart in d3 js with a threshold boundary

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I’ve created a bubble chart of a simple biostat data with varying sized circles based on a person’s age.

This is how it looks:

[image]

What I’d like to do is create a threshold boundary so that a node with age greater than some threshold would be inside the circle and rest will be outside. Also, larger the circle (the one with higher age), the closer it should be to the center (to achieve this I simply sorted the data in non-increasing order). I’ve used d3-force to do this but it isn’t consistent.

My approach :

For some threshold t, the force on the nodes with age >= t would be towards the center of the circle. For the rest of the nodes, the force would be towards the circle’s parameter. But this isn’t consistent, sometimes it just looks like a mess:

[image]

How do I do this correctly? Am I misinterpreting something in my logic? Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still new to d3.js.

Here's what I've done :

```
var width = 1200;
var height = 800;
var RADIUS = 250;
var THRESHOLD = 31;

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

var ageScale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([1, 60]).range([5, 60]);
var redScale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([10, 60]).range([0, 255]);
var greenScale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0, 60]).range([255, 0]);

var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;

var forceX = d3.forceX(d => {
    x = Math.cos(angle) * (RADIUS + 100);
    let age = parseInt(d.Age);
    let threshold = parseInt(THRESHOLD);

    if (age <= threshold) {
        return x + width / 2;
    }
    else {
        return width / 2;
    }
}).strength(0.05);

var forceY = d3.forceY(d => {
    y = Math.sin(angle) * (RADIUS + 100);
    let age = parseInt(d.Age);
    let threshold = parseInt(THRESHOLD);

    if (age <= threshold) {
        return y + height / 2;
    }
    else {
        return height / 2;
    }
}).strength(0.05);

var forceCollide = d3.forceCollide(d => {
    return ageScale(d.Age) + 2;
});


var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("x", forceX)
    .force("y", forceY)
    .force("collide", forceCollide);

function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.Age > b.Age) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.Age < b.Age) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

d3.csv("biostats.csv", function (datapoints) {
    svg.append('circle')
        .attr('cx', width / 2)
        .attr('cy', height / 2)
        .attr('r', RADIUS)
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('opacity', 0.2);

    var circles = svg.selectAll(".artist")
        .data(datapoints)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "artist")
        .attr("r", d => {
            return ageScale(d.Age)
        })
        .attr("fill", d => {
            return `rgb(${redScale(d.Age)}, 0, ${greenScale(d.Age)})`;
            // return 'black';
        })
        .on('click', d => {
            console.log(d);
        });

    datapoints.sort(compare);
    console.log(datapoints);

    simulation.nodes(datapoints).on('tick', ticked);

    function ticked() {
        circles.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
    }
});
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/apoorvpatne10/97f980593a0c1a5f04453edec53e1ab5) with code and sample data included.

Answer (score 2):

Circle packing ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#pack), [example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/circle-packing)) is probably better suited for this than a force layout. With circle packing, you can be sure that the people younger than the threshold will be outside the gray circle and the people older than the threshold will be inside the gray circle. I've used the sorting [recommended](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#node_sort) by the docs, which seems to result in the larger circles being placed closer to the center, but I'm not sure that's a guarantee. I'm not familiar with the layout algorithm.

Here is an example with the data you provided:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>
      // original data
      const people = [
        { Name: "Alex", Sex: "M", Age: 41, Height: 74, Weight: 170 },
        { Name: "Bert", Sex: "M", Age: 42, Height: 68, Weight: 166 },
        { Name: "Carl", Sex: "M", Age: 32, Height: 70, Weight: 155 },
        { Name: "Dave", Sex: "M", Age: 39, Height: 72, Weight: 167 },
        { Name: "Elly", Sex: "F", Age: 30, Height: 66, Weight: 124 },
        { Name: "Fran", Sex: "F", Age: 33, Height: 66, Weight: 115 },
        { Name: "Gwen", Sex: "F", Age: 26, Height: 64, Weight: 121 },
        { Name: "Hank", Sex: "M", Age: 30, Height: 71, Weight: 158 },
        { Name: "Ivan", Sex: "M", Age: 53, Height: 72, Weight: 175 },
        { Name: "Jake", Sex: "M", Age: 32, Height: 69, Weight: 143 },
        { Name: "Kate", Sex: "F", Age: 47, Height: 69, Weight: 139 },
        { Name: "Luke", Sex: "M", Age: 34, Height: 72, Weight: 163 },
        { Name: "Myra", Sex: "F", Age: 23, Height: 62, Weight: 98 },
        { Name: "Neil", Sex: "M", Age: 36, Height: 75, Weight: 160 },
        { Name: "Omar", Sex: "M", Age: 38, Height: 70, Weight: 145 },
        { Name: "Page", Sex: "F", Age: 31, Height: 67, Weight: 135 },
        { Name: "Quin", Sex: "M", Age: 29, Height: 71, Weight: 176 },
        { Name: "Ruth", Sex: "F", Age: 28, Height: 65, Weight: 131 },
      ];

      // set up

      const margin = { top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0};

      const width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right;
      const height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const svg = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

      const g = svg.append('g')
          .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

      // create hierachy

      const groupByAgeThreshold = d3.group(people, d => d.Age >= 31);

      const hierarchy = d3.hierarchy({
        // root node
        children: [
          // circle containing people over 31
          { children: groupByAgeThreshold.get(true) },
          // people younger than 31 are outside that circle
          ...groupByAgeThreshold.get(false)
        ]
      })
        // this will let us size the circles according to age
        .sum(d => d.Age)
        .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

      const pack = d3.pack()
          .padding(5)
          .size([width, height]);

      const root = pack(hierarchy);

      // color scale

      const color = d3.scaleSequential()
          .domain([0, d3.max(people, d => d.Age)])
          .interpolator(d3.interpolateReds);

      // draw circles

      g.selectAll('circle')
        // slice(1) skips the root node
        .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
        .join('circle')
          .attr('r', d => d.r)
          .attr('cx', d => d.x)
          .attr('cy', d => d.y)
          .attr('fill', d => d.children ? '#cccccc' : color(d.data.Age));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I'll check out the docs as well. Any idea why the sorting is not a guarantee?

Comment: The packing algorithm is based on [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1124772.1124851). It might shed some light on how the position of the circles are calculated.